# What can I hook to confirm I don't touch the VCL from outside the main thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, vcl

I'm new to threaded programming. (in XE7)

I'm nervous that I may have inadvertently called procedures that access the VCL from a thread.  My understanding is that this is dangerous.

I've added the code below to some of my procedures that touch the VCL.

```
(*$IFDEF DEBUG *)
    Assert((Windows.GetCurrentThreadId = System.MainThreadID), "Thread error");
(*$ENDIF *)
```

Hopefully, this will catch any calls I made to my VCL-accessing procedures while in a thread.

It occurred to me that if I could insert this code into some VCL low-level code, that it would be more effective at catching illegal VCL access from a thread.

I have never dug into the VCL code, so I'm asking for feedback.  Is there some central place in the VCL code that would be a good place for this code?

TComponent.Create is a nice low level place, but I'm not concerned with controls being created. I'm more concerned with accessing properties (.Left, .Checked) etc.

TIA

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't any suitable low level place in VCL for such code to achieve what you want. If there would be I bet that something similar would have been implemented long ago.

Comment: Just like @SilverWarior says. You would actually have to *inject* every single property setter. And what is worse, not all properties have setters. Btw. your test might not bother WinAPI and could be shortened to `(Self.)ThreadID <> (System.)MainThreadID`.

Comment: You mean '=', right?

Comment: Teoretically you could achieve something similar on a memory manager level provided that memory manager would manage your application memory in certain way to be able to organize stored memory data in such way to know which data belongs to which thread and then make needed checking every time data would be either read or written into memory. But that would seriously hurt memory performance and therefore the overal performance of your application.

Comment: Usually people struggle with this when they want to push everything in some secondary thread because they think that it will improve performance. Multithreading is great if you know when to use it.

Comment: @Sertac '=' definitely

Comment: Is this really even necessary? Unless you're trying to debug a large, bug ridden, tightly coupled, badly written legacy application with mind-bending side-effects then there really is absolutely no need for this sort of thing. You say you're new to multithreading - this tells me you haven't written much (if any) code yet and, therefore, don't have to worry about finding mysterious bad code hidden away somewhere. Just make sure you don't write mysterious bad code and you should be fine. It ought to be immediately obvious when you are writing a line of code whether or not you are touching VCL.

Comment: That said, if you *are* working with a pre-existing codebase and you are trying to write threads into it then it's not just VCL you have to worry about, it's everything else too - anytime anything is shared between threads you need to take care that it's done correctly. If you just start calling methods that belong to other units or other objects without thinking you'll end up in as much or more trouble as you will by modifying VCL in the wrong thread.

Comment: @J... is right. This isn't necessary. You just have to write the code correctly. Just like any other code that you write. It's more tricky with threading code because threaded bugs tend to be less repeatable. So you just need to be disciplined.

Comment: Thanks for all the input.   What I hear J an David saying is "Just be careful and write the code right the first time."  Maybe you guys are better programmers than me, but I don't like walking a tightrope without a net. I make mistakes. And I like to catch them before ship my code.

Comment: @RobertFrank You can convert existing code to threads, it just needs to be done in carefully planned and meticulous manner. Your best bet is to look at the pieces that are slow and can benefit from threading.

Comment: @RobertFrank It's not that hard, really - start from a firm rule that a thread should call no method nor use any field or object that it-itself does not own or create and has exclusive access to.    If you're calling a shared method, make sure it is stateless.   From there, you only need to worry about getting information into the thread and getting it back out again. Otherwise, narrowing down these interfaces lets you focus on a few critical points of entry or exit that need to be made threadsafe (in some manner or other) and the rest just sort of falls into line.

Comment: @Robert The safety net you imagine is illusory. Even if you could implement it (you cannot) it would only help with one particular class of error. There aren't any shortcuts here. You have to really understand the issues to write correct threaded code.

Comment: Or, to put it another way - if you are sufficiently well versed in the problem to program a fully effective, automated, "safety-net" then you must, ipso facto, also be sufficiently well versed in the problem to write bug-free code in the first place.  Attempting to solve the problem by coding yourself a safety net (that actually works) is, if not entirely impossible, an altogether more advanced task than simply coming to terms with the do-s and don't-s of multithreaded programming (and writing good code in the first place).

Comment: Thanks all. I'd like to flag this as answered, but you're all to modest to post   an answer.  Someone please do so.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done.

One thing that goes a little bit in that direction is the `TVirtualMethodInterceptor` in System.Rtti. You could use that to hook all virtual methods of some common classes like TControl or TCheckbox. Things like SetChecked or SetBounds are implemented as virtual methods. So you might be able to hook these. But you'd still have to proxify every instance of these classes.
Look at the Delphi help for an example.

Comment: That would not be very useful. Vast swathes of functionality are implemented in non-virtual methods. If the answer is "it cannot be done", then so be it.